# What's the rationale for the 24 hour wait period for bounties to reward existing answers?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I posted [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162547/why-is-pearsons-%CF%81-only-an-exhaustive-measure-of-association-if-the-joint-distri), which received two outstanding answers.

Since I can only select one as correct I decided to award a bounty to the other one.

I thought it might be preferable if bounties of this sort could skip the wait period and just be awarded immediately. This would mean they don't sit in the 'featured' column for a day. It's not that I mind waiting to award the bounty, but it seems to me that a question which already has an answer worthy of an extra bounty is the least likely question to need additional featuring.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(before looking at the linked question, as a general principle)

One advantage of featuring an answer you take the trouble to award a bonus to is that more users get to see a very good answer or answers, benefit from it, and upvote it (or all of the useful answers) as well. It's often hard to get reputation here - especially for newer users - so good answers deserve any recognition they can get.

It also gives us the chance to upvote a question that drew good answers (which suggests it is worth an upvote). Don't miss the chance to let your reputation show those good answers to others for at least one day. [Some answer-awarders leave it a week to give maximum exposure to the good answer.]

I applaud your choice to accept one and bounty the other; I've done the same when faced with a difficult choice.

(after looking at the linked question)

Ah, *that* question. Well, whuber and myself, we at least don't need reputation, but I'm glad you found the answers helpful.

Comment: Another advantage of waiting the week out is that the additional attention sometimes produces improvements to the original question or answers, particularly due to the insights added by fresh eyeballs in the comments.